# How can I define a max width for content in post editor based on a page template?

Tags: post-editor

On the front end of my theme, a standard post/page is max-width: 693px. But I have a full-width page template that when chosen adds a class to make the max-width: 1072px.

My question is, in the custom-editor-style.css file in my theme (loaded when the editor is open), how can I set the max-width to 693px normally, but 1072px when the current page is the full width page template? The editor doesn't have the same class that is added on the front end when it's a full width page.

Currently in my custom-editor-style.css file I have:

```
.wp-editor { max-width: 693px; }
```

which accounts for the regular page/post width, but is there a way I can account for if the editor is open and the page template is full width?